# Rails ActiveJob not using correct adapter when specified in a custom initialiser

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activejob, sucker-punch

I'm attempting to get ActiveJob to use the sucker-punch adapter with the below code in config/initilizers/sucker_punch.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
 config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sucker_punch
end
```

With this code in place ActiveJob still uses the inline adapter. If I move this code into config/application.rb it works no problem.

I can log from my custom initialiser so I know it is being called.

Versions:

- Rudy 2.2.1
- Rails 4.2.1
- Sucker Punch 1.4.0

Could someone please help.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it may be linked to the initialization order